# iframe is blank when loading word document inside iframe using WordOnline

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sharepoint

I am trying to show a word document inside an iframe of html page. The word document is stored in sharepoint.
I have written code something like below:

`<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://example.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/pathToDoc' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>`

The iframe is blank as shown below:

Could anyone please help me out to show the document in Word Online either inside this iframe OR in a new browser tab?

[image]

Comment: Does your browser console show any error?  Possibly about X-Frame-Options

Comment: Nope.. I do not get any error though. I just get this warning: `Content Security Policy: Directive ‘child-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘worker-src’ to control workers, or directive ‘frame-src’ to control frames respectively.`

Comment: That's a server side issue as far as I'm concerned, try using a different/older browser

Comment: But our requirement is to use IE only. I cant use any other browser. Anyways I tried on Firefox and Chrome, doesnt work there either.